# screens from react-navigation are pushed below React Native's Modal

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-navigation

i want to psuh new screen on top off a model in [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)
**Current Behavior**

The react-native `Modal` is the highest zIndex. All the screens pushed onto the `StackNavigator` by react-navigation are below it.

[react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)

**Expected Behavior**

The new screen should be pushed on top of the react-native Modal

**How to reproduce**

render a react-native `Modal` with some boilerplate code, and then on tap button in your custom modal, just run

`this.props.navigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAME);`

Comment: how you are creating the modal / stack navigator?

Comment: can't pop modal before going to other page

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: @nima_moradi Can't pop modal in my certain usecase. modal is required to be stacked under the new page.

Comment: @locropulenton Modal is created using the `<Modal> </Modal>` imported from React Native. And it is displayed with boolean from state. Check this : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Comment: @darkermuffin Did you resolve this issue? Any idea to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation Implements the modal on root level. So there is no way to push anything on the top of modal.
If you want to achieve this behavior you might create a stack navigator with mode `modal`
[Here is a link of an expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@shoaibkhazer1/opening-a-full-screen-modal-%7C-react-navigation?platform=android&name=Opening%20a%20full-screen%20modal%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Ffull-screen-modal.js)